# If $x = y$ what is $p(x\mid y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I don't speak maths too well (engineer) so simple language preferred or could you describe it as a graph please?

This has probably been asked but I have no idea what to search...

Follow up question:

$$s = w_1 - w_2$$

What is $p(s \mid w_1,w_2)$?

Edit: my top guess if that both are just uniform distributions, as you have no other priors.

edit2: the wider question:

$p(y \mid w_1,w_2) = \int\int p(y \mid t) p(t \mid s) p(s \mid w_1,w_2) dsdt$

y is the outcome of a 'game'

$t \sim N(t \mid s, 1)$

$s = w_1 - w_2$

So the explanation i have jotted down is that $p(y \mid t)$ is a step function.  I reckon $p(t \mid s)$ is a gaussian centred wherever s (the skill difference) is. this all makes sense. im just trying to get a handle on the last term...

Furthermore, the notes go on to day the above integral simplifies:

$p(y \mid w_1,w_2) = \int\int p(y \mid t) p(t \mid s) p(s \mid w_1,w_2) dsdt = \int p(y \mid t) p(t \mid w_1,w_2) dt$

Using the delta function explanation that was the accepted answer, this sort of makes sense in my head as "integrating over s sifts out a gaussian probability distribution of t that is dependent on w1 and w2". the whole variable vs known stuff that is eluded to in the answer comments goes over my head a bit but sort of explains the form above.

Comment: What is s, w1, w2 ?

Comment: variables. like x, y z. (continuous variables)

Comment: By the letter $P$ I guess these are *random* variables.

Comment: i think some kind person is formatting my question with latex =D

Comment: I'm not sure $P(x|y)$ makes sense when $x,y$ are numeric random variables rather than just true-false random variables.

Comment: does a uniform distribution work? im just trying to get a picture in my head of this and some other distributions to follow some maths through roughly. its engineering maths, so potentially sloppy

Comment: So how did you come up with this problem? If you can elaborate further, I am sure we can help you.

Comment: im following throgh some lecture notes on machine learning. this is a ranking algorithm. w1 and w2 are the skills of 'players'. s is the skill difference. p(s|w1,w2) is used in a larger integral (integrating against s and another variable, t). I was trying to get an intuitive feel for what was going on

Comment: hang on, ill try andlatex up the maths ...

Comment: Careful with the notations.. $t\sim \mathcal{N}(t| s,1)$ doesn't mean anything to me. Use $t\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for a univariate normal distribution.

Comment: transcribed from lecture notes :) doesnt mean anything to me either lol

Comment: although i would guess the "$t \mid$" arent supposed to be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether x and y are random or deterministic variables, if they are equal, then $p(x|y) = \delta_y(x)$ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta function. Same goes for s: $p(s|w_1,w_2) = \delta_{w_1-w_2}(s)$.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta for more details :)

Comment: great! i was just thinking of a delta function. so i could describe it as a delta function that sits wherever y is

Comment: this tallies with what i was thinking for the middle term of the integral - it is a gaussian that moves around to wherever s is

Comment: Exactly, but honestly I didn't understand the "wider question". I hope this answer is sufficient.

Comment: so, just to be clear on this answer: $\delta_{w_1-w_2}(s) = \delta_{s}(s)$?

Comment: Formally, no. But I think you understand. s is a variable, therefore $\delta_s(s)$ doesn't mean anything. In the above, $w_1,w_2$ are known, and so the way I wrote it is the correct way.

Comment: maths is confusing, but thank-you :)